# Как отследить нажатие на sprite?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я могу узнать куда нажал пользователь:

```
Input.touches[0].position
```

А как я могу проверить находится ли этот клик на определенной картинке?

Comment: Определенная картинка рисуется с помощью Unity UI или SpriteRenderer?

Comment: @vmchar, Unity Ui. Я нашел способ с помощью Collider. Может еще есть способ?

Answer (score 1):

Помимо самого очевидного решения (повесить Collider на объект и проверять входит ли клик по координатам в границы Collider), можно повесить скрипт на любой Unity UI объект и в нем реализовать интерфейс [IPointerClickHandler](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IPointerClickHandler.html), тогда `EventSystem` будет воспринимать клики по этому объекту и вызывать метод `OnPointerClick(PointerEventData pointerEventData)`.

Кроме реализации интерфейса, на сцене должна быть `EventSystem`, и она должна быть настроена принимать клики. В целом по умолчанию, при создании `Canvas`, все будет настроено достаточно для простейшего использования. В документации также описано, что подобный подход можно реализовать и для не Unity UI объектов, правда для этого потребуется сделать несколько дополнительных шагов.

Comment: Если работа с `UI` то можно обойтись и без написания кода.  Достаточно добавить на объект компонент `Event Trigger` и в нем добавить интересующее вас событие: например `PointerDown`. Дальше остается сделать настройку черед `Editor` Данный подход может не работать для мультитач приложений. Дело в том, что когда вы уже коснулись тача в одной части экрана, второе касание может не обрабатываться как ожидается. В таком случае придется реализовывать через детектор `Collider` и Raycast. 
P.S.:У элемента обязательно должен быть включен признак Raycast Target.